# Run breakpoint after certain loop in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Can I run breakpoint after certain loop in XCode? Since I have very many breakpoints, I don't want to disable the breakpoint one by one then enable again or click the run breakpoint over times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  NSLog(@"Hi!");               /* Breakpoint here */
  ...
  ...                          /* And more breakpoints */
  ...
}
```

I want to enable the first breakpoint after certain loop, for example, `i = 53`

Answer (score 3):

Using this shortcut keys **⌘+Y** you can enable or disable **ALL BreakPoint** whenever you want.

To set conditional breakpoint you have to **Edit breakpoint**.

To do this you have to Right click on breakpoint and then select **Edit Breakpoint** and then see below image to set condition on breakpoint.

[image]

Try this it may help you.

Comment: You're also able to click on the little blue arrow, which will become grey, just on the top of the debugger.

Comment: @Rendy Now see my edited answer it will help you to set conditional breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

By right-clicking on a breakpoint, you're able to "edit the breakpoint". So you're able to add a condition (there is no auto-completion so be careful).

There plenty of other condition like "times before stopping", and I think this one is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Although conditional breakpoints slow your program dos quite a bit.

Comment: Hmm...Didn't know that but, I think that when you're running your program under breakpoint to solve a bug, you dont really care if it's slowing your app, don't you?